# Magento - frontend and backend don't have js files

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I installed the magento2 project for the first time.

I installed the "luma" template and made the following commands:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Unfortunately, I still have a problem with reading js files on the front (both frontend and backend).

```
GET http://magento.local/static/version1547468917/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):22 GET http://magento.local/static/version1547468917/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):25 GET http://magento.local/static/version1547468917/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/polyfill.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):23 GET http://magento.local/static/version1547468917/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):25 GET http://magento.local/static/version1547468917/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/polyfill.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):65 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):65
```

I've tried different solutions. Can any of you help me? This is my first magento project.

Comment: developer mode does not need static-content:deploy if your system is configured currently.

Comment: If I didn't follow this command, it didn't load css and js at all

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: The project is locally (windows) - WAMP

Comment: is the .htaccess file present in your pub/static directory?

Comment: Yes, I have .htaccess file in pub / static